# Which version of JDK and which version of OpenJFX I should use in order to be able to work with WebGL?

Tags: java, javafx, webgl

I'm trying to load into `javafx.scene.web.WebView` a web application with some WebGL invocation in it. I'm aware that `WebGL` was not a thing till the JavaFX 13 and was very excited to learn that it's [finally got supported](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3438896/javafx-13-adds-support-for-native-rendering.html), however what I see personally contradicts to what I find about this issue in the internet.

With following JVM:

- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home

with java version 13.0.2

and with following openjfx artifacts (version 13) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx I'm still failing to see WebGL-powered content.

It's also worth to mentions that searching github for relevant projects doesn't help either.

Comment: Any progress on JavaFX working with WebGL? Did you try contacting Gluon? Did you try JavaFX 14 yet? I need to embed a JS 3D globe in WebView - thanks for any info you can provide!

Comment: @choff from what I see now it's just not a case - it's still impossible (